# Find all Posts where last comments by guest and left at yesterday

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Morning guys,

I am thinking of how to write it easily and effectively

So I've got Posts table(id, user_id, created_at) and Comments table(id, user_id, post_id, created_at).
I need finding all posts where their last comment was left by the guest user(user_id is NULL) and from yesterday. So those posts should not have comments from today but should have at least one for yesterday. And the **LAST** comment from yesterday should be added by the guest user(no other comments after this).

I am able to get what I need but it's hard to write a smart query to be performed efficiently. The estimated number of records in the result is more than 1k(we have thousands of new posts every day and ten thousands of new comments).

Does it make sense to add an index on created_at fields and maybe I'd have to denormalize my data somehow in order to achieve the good results(up to 500ms at worst case)

Any thoughts are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your existing query, table structure and indexes

Comment: Structure of indexes can be flexible. The table fields are pretty obvious 
POSTS(ID, user_id, created_at, ...) --- COMMENTS(ID, user_id, post_id, created_at...)
Thanks

Comment: Anyone, please?...

Comment: Post your actual query as @mohdatif  requested - not a repetition of your table description. Further post the actual table DDL including all indexes and the explain plan for the query.

Answer (score 2):

You did not show your current query. One option would be to write this with a lateral join that retrieves the last comment per `post_id`, and then a filter in the `where` clause:

```
select *
from posts p
cross join lateral (
    select c.*
    from comments c
    where c.post_id = p.id
    order by c.created_at desc limit 1
) c
where c.user_id is null
```

This query should take advantage of an index on `comments(post_id, created_at desc, user_id)` (or possibly `comments(post_id, created_at desc, user_id)`).

We could also try and pre-filter the comments table with `distinct on`:

```
select *
from posts p
inner join (
    select distinct on (post_id) *
    from comments 
    order by post_id, created_at desc
) c on c.post_id = p.id
where c.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using EXPLAIN ANALYZE? This should help you investigate whether adding indexes improves your query times, though if you haven't used it before you'll no doubt need to invest some time in learning how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the posts *and* for efficiency, I would recommend:

```
select c.post_id
from (select distinct on (post_id) c.*
      from comments c
      where c.created_on >= current_date - interval '1 day'
      order by post_id, created_on desc
     ) c
where c.created_on < current_date and
      c.user_id is null;
```

For this, you want an index on `comments(created_on, post_id)`.